# SAP Business One - How can I program a web service and what tools

Tags: php, api, soap, sapb1

A customer of mine uses SAP B1. I am currently programming a web portal (PHP) for him, using a REST, SOAP interface. I have read, there is an Extension (B1 Integration Framework) with which one can program such services.

Well, anyway, my problem is that I have no idea at all from SAP and could not even figure out how I can make such a development in my local environment, or which software I use to and for testing. I have no license for B1 and there is no Developer Trial.

Can one of the SAP aficionados here perhaps bring me on the right path?

Cheers, Thomas